# Mayavi/Python Plotting an image from an irregular array as a vertical plane

Tags: python, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

Here is what I am trying to do: 
I have a surface that I want a plot in 3D and an array that I want plot underneath the surface as a vertical plane. The surface and the plane should form a T model visualization.
The array contains values and I have the corresponding x and y coordinates of the values stored in 2 other arrays (the spacing is irregular).

This is what I have been trying so far...:

```
#!/usr/bin/env/python2

import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

def test_surf():

    def f(x,y):
        sin, cos = np.sin, np.cos
        #return sin(x + y) + sin(2 * x - y) + cos(3 * x + 4 * y)
        return sin(x) + cos(y)

    x, y = np.mgrid[-7.:7.05:0.1, -5.:5.05:0.05]
    s = mlab.surf(x, y, f)
    return s


def add_2dimage():

    im = np.random.random((15,15))
    #x , y = np.mgrid[0:10:1,0:10:1]
    #src = mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(x,y,im)
    im = im[:, np.newaxis, :]
    src = mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(im)
    image = mlab.pipeline.surface(src)
    return image

if __name__ == "__main__":

    test_surf()
    add_2dimage()
    mlab.show()
```

Comment: What is a "T model visualization" and what do you mean by "an array that I want plot underneath the surface as a vertical plane" ?

Comment: The surface and the vertical plane should form a "T", the 3D surface being the horizontal part of the T and the 2D plane the xy array plotted as an image...